# Matlab: program stops iterating at random times before "for" loop is completed

Tags: matlab, for-loop, random, queue, simulation

Writing a program in MATLAB which simulates wait times in a queue. Currently, it's supposed to assign a queue entrance and exit time (in seconds) to all 855 jobs. However, each time I run it, it picks a random point in time and stops assigning queue entrance times to jobs arriving after this time. Perhaps a problem with my random number generator? Here's my code:

```
function waitTimes = mcQueue2(arrivals, services)
% inputs the array of absolute arrival times and service times for each
% voter, places them into queue and service, 
% RECORDS WAIT TIME

secsOpen = 46800; 
arrivalArray = arrivalTimes(arrivals); % uses xlsread to make an array from an excel 
% file of times, in seconds, from 1 to secsOpen when jobs arrive
serviceArray = generateServiceTimes(services); % generateServiceTimes reads an input 
% array from an excel sheet, counts its elements, creates an array of that number of 
% elements, and populates each element with a random number using logninv()

arrivalArray(1) = 1; % set the first arrival to arrive at the first second
serversBusy = [0 0 0 0]; % each time a job exits queue and begins service, the service 
% time associated with that job is added to the serversBusy time of whichever server is 
% handling 
numMachines = numel(serversBusy);
arrivalIndex = 1;
queue = []; 
numInQueue = zeros(1, secsOpen); % tracks how many people are in queue each second
waitTimes = cat(2, (1:numel(arrivalArray))', zeros(numel(arrivalArray), 2));

for sec = 1:secsOpen
    % every second, check if someone is arriving that second
    if arrivalArray(arrivalIndex) == sec
        % if they arrive, put them into the queue
        queue = cat(2, queue, arrivalIndex);
        % record the time they entered queue
        waitTimes(arrivalIndex, 2) = sec;
        % increment arrivalIndex to wait for the next arrival
        arrivalIndex = arrivalIndex + 1;
    end
    %check if any of the servers are becoming available
    for ii = 1:numMachines
        if serversBusy(ii) <= sec && numel(queue) > 0
        % if so, send the first voter in queue to the server
            % record the current time as the time they exited queue
            waitTimes(queue(1), 3) = sec; 
            % add this job's service time to the time the server is busy until
            serversBusy(ii) = sec + serviceArray(queue(1));
            % remove the job from the queue
            queue(1) = [];
        end
    end
    numInQueue(sec) = length(queue);
end
plot(1:sec, numInQueue, '*')
end
```

With the current spreadsheets I input to arrivalTimes and generateServiceTime, there should be 855 jobs arriving at the server. The most recent time I ran the code, for example, it assigned arrival and exit times to the first 27 arrivals and then nothing for the remaining 828 elements. Here's an example of waitTimes:

```
       1           1           1
       2          51          51
       3         188         188
       4         190         190
       5         231         231
       6         329         399
       7         355         400
       8         505         505
       9         633         633
      10         734         734
      11         739         762
      12         804         905
      13         852        1137
      14         914        1185
      15         974        1205
      16         976        1225
      17        1066        1489
      18        1068        1537
      19        1074        1558
      20        1097        1778
      21        1132        1798
      22        1170        1892
      23        1208        1960
      24        1271        2096
      25        1299        2158
      26        1304        2176
      27        1354        2268
      28           0           0
      29           0           0
      30           0           0
```

(Zeros continue past 30 to 855) The output for 1 to 27 is exactly what I want. Why won't it keep doing this for the rest of the elements in the list??

Here's the code for arrivalTimes and generateServiceTime:

```
function arrivals = arrivalTimes(excelFile)
% inputs an excel file of the template 'SamplePrecincts.xlsx' outputs the
% array of arrival times
% the excelFile contains the interarrival times between jobs, so arrivalTimes sums them     
% to get the absolute time when the job arrives.
interarrivals = (xlsread(excelFile, 'Sheet2', 'D1:ALN5'))';
interarrivals(~any(interarrivals,2), : ) = []; % get rid of any zeros
arrivals = zeros(size(interarrivals, 1), size(interarrivals, 2));
arrivals(1) = 0;
for k = 2:numel(interarrivals)
    arrivals(k) = arrivals(k-1) + interarrivals(k);
end
end
```

each cell in excelFile Sheet2 D1:ALN5 has the following formula:

```
 FLOOR.MATH(GAMMA.INV(RAND(), 1, $C$2))
```

where C2 is currently 53.9731

```
function serviceTimes = generateServiceTimes(excelFile)
% takes an input of the template 'SamplePrecincts.xlsx' and generates
% lognormal vote times based on the YKA paper. returns in seconds
interarrivals = (xlsread(excelFile, 'Sheet2', 'D1:ALN5'))';
interarrivals(~any(interarrivals,2), : ) = []; % get rid of any zeros
[r, c] = size(interarrivals);
voteTimes = zeros(r, c);
for k = 1:numel(voteTimes)
    voteTimes(k) = ceil(60*logninv(rand(), 1.7042, 0.4406));
end
end
```

Comment: I guess that the above output is from the `waitTimes` variable.  The first column is from the `arrivalArray` which is read in from an Excel file (?) using the `arrivalTimes` function.  Are you sure that each element of `arrivalArray` is an integer that can be compared identically with `arrivalArray(arrivalIndex) == sec`?  What does the code for `arrivalTimes` look like, and what would a sample input `arrivals` look like too?

Comment: Thanks for the input, turns out I fixed it on my own! I got rid of the `arrivals` and `services` arguments and replaced it with an `excelFile` argument which is used as the argument for `arrivalTimes()` and `generateServiceTimes()`

Comment: WAIT Turns out that did not help, I just randomly got it to iterate 600 times instead of 855 times.

Comment: Sean - you need to print out the `arrivalArray` data.  What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the range `'D1:ALN5'` corresponds to 5*999 = 4995 entries (= jobs), so I am not sure how that fits your value of 855 jobs.

I looked into your problem, and I think I know what your problem is:
When you load the `arrivaltimes`, you only get rid of the zeros if there is a whole collumn only consisting of zeros.

My suggestion is make `arrivaltimes` a vector instead of a matrix, for example by adding the following line `interarrivals = interarrivals(:);` just after the line `interarrivals = (xlsread(excelFile, 'Sheet2', 'D1:ALN5'))';` in the `arrivalTimes`-function.

Notice that this will not stop the `waitTimes` variable from having a lot of zeros in the end: Zeros in the second collumn means that the job never gets to be started (before the `secsOpen` limit). And zeros in the third collumn means that the job never get to finish (before the `secsOpen` limit).

Notice also that you will get an error (this might happen if you have fewer jobs (like the 855 you wrote first) or have a higher `secsOpen`-value) if the last job is started before the time reaches the `secsOpen` limit, this can however easily be salvaged by changing the line `if arrivalArray(arrivalIndex) == sec` to `if (arrivalIndex <= numel(arrivalArray)) && (arrivalArray(arrivalIndex) == sec)` in the `waitTimes`-function.

I hope this solves your problem!